# Dynamic ListView scroll TextView changed automatically

Tags: android, listview

[image: Here is my image]

when i click + button increment the price and click - button decrease the price it's work perfectly but when i scroll listview the value of tvPrices (TextView) is changed.

What should i do for the stay increment price?

**here is my adapter**

```
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 public ArrayList<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 public ArrayList<Integer> price = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 private String[] listViewItems, prices, static_price;
 TypedArray images;
 View row = null;

 static String get_price, get_quntity;
 int g_quntity, g_price, g_minus;

 private Context context;
 CustomButtonListener customButtonListener;

 static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();


 public ListAdapter(Context context, String[] listViewItems, TypedArray images, String[] prices) {
  this.context = context;
  this.listViewItems = listViewItems;
  this.images = images;
  this.prices = prices;

  for (int i = 0; i < listViewItems.length; i++) {
   quantity.add(0);
   price.add(0);
  }
 }

 public void setCustomButtonListener(CustomButtonListener customButtonListner) {
  this.customButtonListener = customButtonListner;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return listViewItems.length;
 }

 @Override
 public String getItem(int position) {
  return listViewItems[position];
 }


 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  final ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
  if (convertView == null) {
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_listview, parent, false);
   listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
   listViewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
   listViewHolder.ivProduct = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivproduct);
   listViewHolder.tvPrices = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
   listViewHolder.btnPlus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_addnew);
   listViewHolder.edTextQuantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
   listViewHolder.btnMinus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_remove);
   static_price = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Price);
   row.setTag(listViewHolder);
  } else {
   row = convertView;
   listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }


  listViewHolder.ivProduct.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(position, -1));


  try {

   listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText(quantity.get(position) + "");

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  listViewHolder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (customButtonListener != null) {
     customButtonListener.onButtonClickListener(position, listViewHolder.edTextQuantity, 1);

     quantity.set(position, quantity.get(position) + 1);
     price.set(position, price.get(position) + 1);

     row.getTag(position);

     get_price = listViewHolder.tvPrices.getText().toString();

     g_price = Integer.valueOf(static_price[position]);

     get_quntity = listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString();
     g_quntity = Integer.valueOf(get_quntity);

     map.put("" + listViewHolder.tvProductName.getText().toString(), " " + listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString());
     listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText("" + g_price * g_quntity);
//                    Log.d("A ", "" + a);
//                    Toast.makeText(context, "A" + a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    Log.d("Position ", "" + position);
//                    System.out.println(+position + " Values " + map.values());
     ShowHashMapValue();
     listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText("" + g_price * g_quntity);
    }


   }

  });
  listViewHolder.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (customButtonListener != null) {
     customButtonListener.onButtonClickListener(position, listViewHolder.edTextQuantity, -1);
     if (quantity.get(position) > 0)
      quantity.set(position, quantity.get(position) - 1);

     get_price = listViewHolder.tvPrices.getText().toString();
     g_minus = Integer.valueOf(get_price);
     g_price = Integer.valueOf(static_price[position]);
     int minus = g_minus - g_price;
     if (minus >= g_price) {
      listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText("" + minus);
     }

     map.put("" + listViewHolder.tvProductName.getText().toString(), " " + listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString());
     ShowHashMapValue();
    }
   }
  });
  listViewHolder.tvProductName.setText(listViewItems[position]);
  listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText(prices[position]);

  return row;
 }

 private void ShowHashMapValue() {

  /**
   * get the Set Of keys from HashMap
   */
  Set setOfKeys = map.keySet();

/**
 * get the Iterator instance from Set
 */
  Iterator iterator = setOfKeys.iterator();

/**
 * Loop the iterator until we reach the last element of the HashMap
 */
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
/**
 * next() method returns the next key from Iterator instance.
 * return type of next() method is Object so we need to do DownCasting to String
 */
   String key = (String) iterator.next();

/**
 * once we know the 'key', we can get the value from the HashMap
 * by calling get() method
 */
   String value = map.get(key);

   System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: you need to store all updated data in your list and then use adapter.notifydatasetchanged

Comment: Use a recycler view. onBindView() will refresh the item list and keep the values there.

Comment: You are not using the ViewHolder pattern properly that is why data is being changed dynamically as the data in the holder is being used in the wrong places.
Remove `row = convertView`.
The `try-catch` is unnecessary and can be avoided by a simple bounds check.

Comment: Guys .notifydatasetchanged not work in my case.

Comment: What is ViewHolder pattern please provide the example or link **@TheSunny** and Remove row = convertView not work

Answer (score 0):

In onclick, after you decrement the value call notifyDataSetChanged()

[notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

but its a costly operation, since it refreshes complete list