# Strange behavior of custom listview with sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to create a shopping cart app and everything was going great but now i am stuck for last three day did search lot in stackoverflow but could not get a answer.I am populating listview from server and there is two buttons in each row plus(for adding quantity) and minus for (decrements it). This is the screen where i am adding quantity to cart.
[image]
 I am trying to insert row to sqlite database upon clicking either of two buttons and i have achieved this and i am show these data in next activity inside a listview. Here my problem starts when i insert data it shows it properly but during updation it is showing strange behavior. If i click on first three rows the insertion and updation working fine but if i scroll down and click on any item then instead of updating each time its inserting.. I know this question is quite big and lengthy but i could not find a good way to summarize it sorry.. Please help me thanks ..

This is the screen which i am getting as output.
[image]

Here is my ListView class.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

int mCurrentPage;
private ListView listView;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<FeedItem> productsInCart = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
private RelativeLayout content;
private SharedPreferences preference;
TextView badge,prices;
int totalCount=0,newCount = 0;
int lastCount;
int totalPrice;
SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
public static final String TOTAL_COUNT = "count";
DBHelper mHelper;
boolean isUpdate;
String userId,price,pname,position;
private Button checkOut;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Getting the arguments to the Bundle object */
    Bundle data = getArguments();

    /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
    mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);

       recyclerView= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
       content  = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.content);
       badge = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.all_comments);
       checkOut = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.checkOut);
       prices = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.price);
        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
        new JSONAsyncTask()
        .execute("http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json");
        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity(), feedItems);
         recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
         recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        listAdapter.setOnAddNum(this);
        listAdapter.setOnSubNum(this);
        mHelper=new DBHelper(getActivity());

        content.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),CheckOutFooter.class);
                startActivity(i);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition
                (R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
            }
        });

        checkOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (userId != null){

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),CheckOut.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                else{

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cart is empty! Please add few products to cart.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
       });



    return v;
}

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("feed");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject feedObj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                  //  Actors actor = new Actors();
                    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                    item.setObservation(feedObj.optString("name"));
                    item.setSummary(feedObj.optString("timeStamp"));
                    item.setName(feedObj.optString("name"));

                    feedItems.add(item);

                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        if(result == false){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        else{

            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }

        pDialog.dismiss();
        }
      }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     Object tag = (Integer) view.getTag();
     switch (view.getId()){
         case R.id.btnAddToCart1:

            // FeedItem item = feedItems.get(tag);
             if (tag != null && tag instanceof Integer) {

                 int position = (Integer) tag;


    int   num =feedItems.get(position).getNum();
      int price =feedItems.get(position).getPrice();
      String pName = feedItems.get(position).getName();
      String product_name = feedItems.get(position).getName(); 
      num++;
      feedItems.get(position).setNum(num);
      feedItems.get(position).setPrice(position);

      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
              product_name+ " is added to cart!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      preference = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("STATE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      preference.edit().putString("QUANTITY", String.valueOf(num)).apply();
      preference.edit().putString("PRICE", String.valueOf(num*position)).apply();
      preference.edit().putString("PNAME",product_name).apply();
      preference.edit().putString("POSITION",String.valueOf(position)).apply();
      updateData();
      listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

             }
     break;

   case R.id.btnAddToCart5:
       if (tag != null && tag instanceof Integer) {

           int position = (Integer) tag;
           int num =feedItems.get(position).getNum();
           int price =feedItems.get(position).getPrice();
       if (num>0) {
           num--;
           feedItems.get(position).setNum(num);
           feedItems.get(position).setPrice(position);
           preference = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("STATE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           preference.edit().putString("QUANTITY", String.valueOf(num)).apply();
           preference.edit().putString("PRICE", String.valueOf(num*position)).apply();
           preference.edit().putString("POSITION",String.valueOf(position)).apply();
          updateData();
           listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       }

       else{
            num= 0;

            dataBase.delete(
                    DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                    DBHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                            + (position+1), null);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

       }



       break;
     }
 }


public void onResume(){
     super.onResume();

 }

private void updateData() {

    preference = 
            getActivity().getSharedPreferences("STATE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    userId = preference.getString("QUANTITY", null);
    price = preference.getString("PRICE", null);
    pname = preference.getString("PNAME", null);
    position = preference.getString("POSITION", null);

    int counts = Integer.parseInt(position);



    if(userId == null){

        badge.setText("0");

    }
    else{
     checkOut.setEnabled(true);

    badge.setText(String.valueOf(userId));



     dataBase = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();

     /*Cursor curs = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM cart", null);
        if(curs.moveToFirst())
        {

            int total = curs.getInt(0);

            System.out.println("Total Sum of Price : "+total);
            prices.setText(String.valueOf(total)+" Rs/-");

        }
    */
     Cursor  cur = null;
     String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_NAME +
          " WHERE " +DBHelper.KEY_ID+"=?;" ;




        cur = dataBase.rawQuery(query,new String[] {String.valueOf(counts+1)});

       if((cur != null) && (cur.getCount() > 0)){
           dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
         cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_COUNT,userId);
         cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_PRICE, price);
         cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_PNAME, pname);
         System.out.println("Database values : "+cv);
         dataBase.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, cv, DBHelper.KEY_ID+" = '" +
                                        String.valueOf(counts+1) + "'", null);
         cur.close();
       }
       else{
         dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
         cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_COUNT,userId);
         cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_PRICE, price);
         cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_PNAME, pname);
         System.out.println("Database values : "+cv);
         dataBase.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
         cur.close();
       }

    }

}

}
```

My checkout page where i am showing data from sqlite.

```
  public class CheckOut  extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> product_Name = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> product_Quantity = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> product_Price = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> quantityList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> amountList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ListView recyclerView;
    TextView quantity;
    TextView amount;
    Button pay;
    DBHelper mHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.checkout);

    recyclerView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    pay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pay);
    mHelper = new DBHelper(this);


}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    displayData();
    super.onResume();
}


private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);
    int sum = 0;
    int qty = 0;
    userId.clear();
    product_Name.clear();
    product_Quantity.clear();
    quantityList.clear();
    amountList.clear();
    product_Price.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID)));
            product_Name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_PNAME)));
            product_Quantity.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_COUNT)));
            product_Price.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_PRICE)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(CheckOut.this,userId, product_Name, product_Price,product_Quantity);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(disadpt);
    mCursor.close();

    quantityList = convertInteger(product_Quantity);
    amountList = converAmountInteger(product_Price);

    for (int i : quantityList){

        qty = qty+i;
    }

    for (int s : amountList){

        sum = sum +s;
    }
    amount.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(qty));

    disadpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


private ArrayList<Integer> converAmountInteger(
        ArrayList<String> product_Price2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     for(String amount : product_Price2) {
            try {
                //Convert String to Integer, and store it into integer array list.
                result.add(Integer.parseInt(amount));
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
               //System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                Log.w("NumberFormat", "Parsing failed! " + amount + " can not be an integer");
            } 
        }       
        return result;
}


private ArrayList<Integer> convertInteger(
        ArrayList<String> product_Quantity2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     for(String quantity : product_Quantity2) {
            try {
                //Convert String to Integer, and store it into integer array list.
                result.add(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
               //System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                Log.w("NumberFormat", "Parsing failed! " + quantity + " can not be an integer");
            } 
        }       
        return result;


}
```

Database class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String DATABASE_NAME="user.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="cart";
public static final String KEY_COUNT="cartItem";
public static final String KEY_PNAME="product_name";
public static final String KEY_ID="id";
public static final String KEY_PRICE="price";
public static final String KEY_CREATED_AT="created_at";


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_COUNT+" INTEGER,"
                                                       +KEY_PNAME+" TEXT,"+KEY_PRICE+" INTEGER,"+ KEY_CREATED_AT
                                                       + " DATETIME" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

**UPDATE :**
There was a little mistake i changed the column name instead of i created a unique key and its working fine..

Comment: what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: i am having issue in updating the row on item button click. When i am inserting its working perfectly but during update  it is not working correctly.If i am updating first row or second row its working but if am scrolling down and trying to update any row it is not updating rather inserting each time.

Comment: updating in the sense you are updating the count value(plus or minus).?list view items gets recreated whenever the list view is scrolled.it is better to use Model Class.In order to save the state of the current item(updated item).

Comment: i think you are not getting my problem let me add few screenshots so it would be clear

Comment: who downvoted this question.. If anyone is downvoting please explain why?

Comment: yes it would be better..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102882/discussion-between-nitesh-kumar-and-asif-sb).

Comment: same problem i am facing see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921969/dynamic-listview-scroll-textview-changed-automatically

Comment: check out my answer this will definately solve your prob.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35170004/5746722